# What does the expansion symbol of From the Vault: Transform mean?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What does the expansion symbol of From the Vault: Transform depicts? Looks like feathers in a circle to me.

MTG Gamepedia says:

> "The cards use their original transformation symbols. However, the
>   expansion symbol is uniquely mirrored in color on the cards' back
>   sides."

And Wikipedia lists it as

> unrevealed

in the Expansion Symbol column at [List of Magic: The Gathering Sets article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Magic:_The_Gathering_sets)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the Wikipedia Quote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quote is merely referring to the fact the expansion symbols colours on the front are inverted on the back. The standard is for expansion symbols to be the same regardless of what side they are printed on, so this difference in colour makes the set symbol unique.

I suspect that the symbol is supposed to be the back of a werewolf in front of a moon. Though the expansion only contains one werewolf, werewolves are a core part of the transform mechanic and featured heavily in the mechanics debut during Innistrad.

Front (Orange background, Black lines):
[image: Front of Card]

Back (Black background, Orange lines):
[image: Back of Card]

Comment: If I understand right, the question was what it represents, and the OP just quoted those things by way of showing research effort.

Comment: Indeed my question is "What it represents."

Comment: @GadDLord I edited in my interpretation. I think I am not far off as the shape seems pretty similar to Ravager of the Fells back. But it is pretty abstract so we will see...